# PHP: How to print associative array using while loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple associative array.

```
<?php
$assocArray = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
?>
```

Using only while loop, how can I print it in this result?

```
$a = 1 
$b = 2 
$c = 3
```

This is my current solution but I think that this is not the efficient/best way to do it?

```
<?php
$assocArray = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$keys = array_keys($assocArray);
rsort($keys);

while (!empty($keys)) {
    $key = array_pop($keys);
    echo $key . ' = ' . $assocArray[$key] . '<br />';
};
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: like this: `foreach($arr as $key=>$value) { .. }` ?

Comment: Why do you require only while loop?

Comment: check my answer mate it's perfectly how you want........

Comment: Hi Thrustmaster, I know how to do it in foreach and for loop but I don't know the efficient way to do it in while loop so that's why I want to know :)

Comment: How about mine marknt15........it's efficient and good one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this syntax and this is best efficient way to do your job...........

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($array_expression)) {
       statement
}

<?php


$data = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);

print_r($data);

while (list($key, $value) = each($data)) {
       echo '$'.$key .'='.$value;
}

?>
```

For [reference](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-access-php-array-and-multidimensional-nested-arrays-code-syntax/) please check this link.........

Small [Example](http://eval.in/10791) link here...

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm looking for :) I don't use while loop much in my projects, only for and foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

The best and easiest way to loop through an array is using foreach

```
 foreach ($assocArray as $key => $value)
        echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br />';
```

Comment: OP is aking to print them using while loop and not `foreach` function.

Comment: there is not much difference between while and foreach. Final result will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
$assocarray = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$keys = array_keys($assocarray);
rsort($keys);
while (!empty($keys)) {
    $key = array_pop($keys);
    echo $key . ' = ' . $assocarray[$key] . '<br />';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution for this, it will get the job done..

```
$x = array(0=>10,1=>11,2=>"sadsd");

end($x);    
$ekey = key($x);        
reset($x );

while(true){

    echo "<br/>".key($x)." = ".$x[key($x)];

    if($ekey == key($x) )break;
    next($x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
$assocArray = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);

$obj = new ArrayObject($assocArray);

foreach ( $obj as $key => $value ) {
    echo '$' . $key .'='. $value . "<br/>";
}
```